# when i want to do login error appears GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I have a problem with my login page. When I want to login I get this error:

Answer (score 0):

The essence of login is to send request to check login information so you have to use post method with token in laravel 8

```
<form method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```